# How do I write this GROUP BY in mysql UNION query

Tags: mysql, group-by, union

Trying to group the results of two queries together.  When I run this query:

```
SELECT pr_id,
        pr_sbtcode,
        pr_sdesc,
        od_quantity,
        od_amount
FROM (
        SELECT `bgProducts`.`pr_id`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sbtcode`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sdesc`,
                SUM(`od_quantity`) AS `od_quantity`,
                SUM(`od_amount`) AS `od_amount`,
                MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`)) AS `or_date`
        FROM `bgOrderMain`
        INNER JOIN `bgOrderData`
        INNER JOIN `bgProducts`
        WHERE `bgOrderMain`.`or_id` = `bgOrderData`.`or_id`
                AND `od_pr` = `pr_id`
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) >= '1262322000'
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) <= '1346990399'
                AND (
                        `pr_id` = '415'
                        OR `pr_id` = '1088'
                        )
        GROUP BY `bgProducts`.`pr_id`

        UNION

        SELECT `bgProducts`.`pr_id`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sbtcode`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sdesc`,
                SUM(`od_quantity`) AS `od_quantity`,
                SUM(`od_amount`) AS `od_amount`,
                MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`)) AS `or_date`
        FROM `npOrderMain`
        INNER JOIN `npOrderData`
        INNER JOIN `bgProducts`
        WHERE `npOrderMain`.`or_id` = `npOrderData`.`or_id`
                AND `od_pr` = `pr_id`
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) >= '1262322000'
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) <= '1346990399'
                AND (
                        `pr_id` = '415'
                        OR `pr_id` = '1088'
                        )
        GROUP BY `bgProducts`.`pr_id`
        ) TEMPTABLE3;
```

it produces this result

```
+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------+
| pr_id  |  pr_sbtcode  |  pr_sdesc      |  od_quantity  |  od_amount |
+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------+
|   415  |  NP13        |  Product 13    |  5            |  125       |
|  1088  |  NPAW        |  Product AW    |  4            |  100       |
|   415  |  NP13        |  Product 13    |  5            |  125       |
|  1088  |  NPAW        |  Product AW    |  2            |  50        |
+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------+
```

What I want to get a result that combines those into 2 lines:

```
+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------+ 
| pr_id  |  pr_sbtcode  |  pr_sdesc      |  od_quantity  |  od_amount |
+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------+ 
|   415  |  NP13        |  Product 13    |  10           |  250       |
|  1088  |  NPAW        |  Product AW    |  6            |  150       | 
+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------+
```

So I added GROUP BY pr_id to the end of the query:

```
SELECT pr_id,
        pr_sbtcode,
        pr_sdesc,
        od_quantity,
        od_amount
FROM (
        SELECT `bgProducts`.`pr_id`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sbtcode`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sdesc`,
                SUM(`od_quantity`) AS `od_quantity`,
                SUM(`od_amount`) AS `od_amount`,
                MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`)) AS `or_date`
        FROM `bgOrderMain`
        INNER JOIN `bgOrderData`
        INNER JOIN `bgProducts`
        WHERE `bgOrderMain`.`or_id` = `bgOrderData`.`or_id`
                AND `od_pr` = `pr_id`
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) >= '1262322000'
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) <= '1346990399'
                AND (
                        `pr_id` = '415'
                        OR `pr_id` = '1088'
                        )
        GROUP BY `bgProducts`.`pr_id`

        UNION

        SELECT `bgProducts`.`pr_id`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sbtcode`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sdesc`,
                SUM(`od_quantity`) AS `od_quantity`,
                SUM(`od_amount`) AS `od_amount`,
                MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`)) AS `or_date`
        FROM `npOrderMain`
        INNER JOIN `npOrderData`
        INNER JOIN `bgProducts`
        WHERE `npOrderMain`.`or_id` = `npOrderData`.`or_id`
                AND `od_pr` = `pr_id`
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) >= '1262322000'
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) <= '1346990399'
                AND (
                        `pr_id` = '415'
                        OR `pr_id` = '1088'
                        )
        GROUP BY `bgProducts`.`pr_id`
        ) TEMPTABLE3
GROUP BY pr_id;
```

But that just gives me this:

```
+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------+ 
| pr_id  |  pr_sbtcode  |  pr_sdesc      |  od_quantity  |  od_amount |
+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------+ 
|   415  |  NP13        |  Product 13    |  5            |  125       | 
|  1088  |  NPAW        |  Product AW    |  4            |  100       |
+--------+--------------+----------------+---------------+------------+
```

What am I missing here??

Comment: Rock on John Woo... it's hard to edit those monster queries. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

your code is hard to format since you have added `nbsp`. but any way try this one,

***first attemp***

```
SELECT pr_id,
        pr_sbtcode,
        pr_sdesc,
        SUM(od_quantity) totalQuantity,
        SUM(od_amount) totalAmount
FROM 
    (
        SELECT `bgProducts`.`pr_id`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sbtcode`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sdesc`,
                SUM(`od_quantity`) AS `od_quantity`,
                SUM(`od_amount`) AS `od_amount`,
                MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`)) AS `or_date`
        FROM `bgOrderMain`
        INNER JOIN `bgOrderData`
        INNER JOIN `bgProducts`
        WHERE `bgOrderMain`.`or_id` = `bgOrderData`.`or_id`
                AND `od_pr` = `pr_id`
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) >= '1262322000'
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) <= '1346990399'
                AND (
                        `pr_id` = '415'
                        OR `pr_id` = '1088'
                    )
        GROUP BY `bgProducts`.`pr_id`
        UNION
        SELECT `bgProducts`.`pr_id`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sbtcode`,
                `bgProducts`.`pr_sdesc`,
                SUM(`od_quantity`) AS `od_quantity`,
                SUM(`od_amount`) AS `od_amount`,
                MIN(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`)) AS `or_date`
        FROM `npOrderMain`
        INNER JOIN `npOrderData`
        INNER JOIN `bgProducts`
        WHERE `npOrderMain`.`or_id` = `npOrderData`.`or_id`
                AND `od_pr` = `pr_id`
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) >= '1262322000'
                AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP(`or_date`) <= '1346990399'
                AND (
                        `pr_id` = '415'
                        OR `pr_id` = '1088'
                    )
        GROUP BY `bgProducts`.`pr_id`
    ) unionedTable
GROUP BY pr_id,
        pr_sbtcode,
        pr_sdesc
```

## [*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5ad01/2)

Comment: That worked!!!!   Thank you so much!  Geesh, knew it was going to be something simple I just wasn't seeing. Not sure where the nbsp spaces came from as I didn't deliberately add those in....

Comment: you are welcome @user1652368 ! just don't forget to accept answers if you feel it really solves your question :)